# How do I assign a default value to all cells under a certain column?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am a newbie to ms excel and currently I need to create an invoice in MS Excel.What I need is, I have to create a column “Cost” under which a default value of Rs.500 should be set.If I manually add another cost, then the new cost should replace Rs.500.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are being very broad and vague - please show a specific problem we can help you with. Also, I don't think such a "default value" meachanism as you imagine it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should paste the formula below into your Cost column (assuming headers on row 1):

`=IF(A2<>"","Rs.500")`

This means, if A2 is not blank, fill cell with Rs.500

As you add values in the A column, your Cost column will become populated with "Rs.500"

Comment: Defaults to 0 in my case

Answer (score 0):

Set up your table as a structured table (List Object).  Make sure that your column headings are all unique and then select your data (including column headings) and select "Format as Table" from your Home menu.  In the first cell of your Cost column enter ="Rs.500" and press enter. The formula will propagate through the entire column and will be populated as you add rows.